# Avoid branching of null check with Optionals

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Let's say I have the next piece of code:

```
void doSmtng(A a){
    if (a!=null){
        B b = a.getB();
        if (b != null){
            C c = b.getC();
            if (c != null){
                d = c.getD();
            }
        }
    }
    doSmtngWithD(d);
}
```

And let's say I can change the API that instead of getting `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` I can get `Optional<A>`, `Optional<B>` and so on.

What is the right way to write a more aesthetic code that will prevent  all those null checks?
Also, is there a way to do what I asked with the addition of throwing an exception once one of variables (a,b,c,d..) are null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another `Optional` way, which was also mentioned by Holger in the comments:

```
D d = Optional.ofNullable(a)
              .map(A::getB)
              .map(B::getC)
              .map(C::getD)
              .orElseThrow(/* your exception */);
```

This can be applied to your code as is. You do not need to rewrite your accessor methods. The exception is thrown as soon as the first `null` value is returned. But when the exception is thrown you don't know which one exactly is `null`.

If you really want to know that, you are probably better of implementing a simple method, which just does your `null`-checks instead of using `Optional`, e.g.

```
static <T> T mapIfNotNull(T value) {
  if (value == null) {
    // throw your exception...
  }
  return value;
}
```

and use it without your conditions as follows:

```
A a = ...
B b = mapIfNotNull(a.getB());
C c = mapIfNotNull(b.getC());
D d = mapIfNotNull(c.getD());
```

This way you are able to throw your desired exception at each step... (if you supply an additional argument where you deliver your custom exception, e.g. `mapIfNotNull(T value, Supplier<RuntimeException> exceptionSupplier)`).
Or simply use [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-) as Holger states in the comment, if `NullPointerException` suffices your needs.

If you also want to check, whether the object, where you call your `getXX` on is not null, you may want to use a method as the following:

```
static <S, T> T map(S source, Function<S, T> mapFunction) {
  if (source == null) { // or again: Objects.requireNonNull(source,..)
    // throw exception due to source
  }
  T value = mapFunction.apply(source);
  if (value == null) { // or Objects.requireNonNull(value,..)
    // throw exception due to missing value
  }
  return value;
}
```

calling works nearly the same:

```
A a = ...
B b = map(a, A::getB);
C c = map(b, B::getC);
D d = map(c, C::getD);
```

Comment: Note that your `mapIfNotNull` [already exists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-). So you can use `a = Objects.requireNonNull(a, "a"); B b = Objects.requireNonNull(a.getB(), "b");  C c =Objects.requireNonNull(b.getC(), "c");  D d = Objects.requireNonNull(c.getD(), "d");`

Comment: You are right regarding `requireNonNull`/ `NullPointerException`. When I wrote it I had a custom exception in mind ;-)

Comment: Thanks nonetheless :-)

Answer (score 5):

Starting with `Optional<A> a` :

```
a.flatMap(A::getOptionalB)
   .flatMap(B::getOptionalC)
   .flatMap(C::getOptionalD)
   .ifPresent(d -> doSomethingWithD(d));
```

If you want to throw an exception if one of those is missing:

```
D d = a.flatMap(A::getOptionalB)
       .flatMap(B::getOptionalC)
       .flatMap(C::getOptionalD)
       .orElseThrow(() -> new SomeKindOfException());
doSomethingWithD(d);
```

Comment: @Holger From the question: "let's say I can change the API that instead of getting A,B,C,D I can get `Optional<A>`, `Optional<B>` and so on"

Comment: what if I want to know which was the first missing?

Comment: I see. But it’s *more complicated* than just keeping the methods as-is and use, e.g. `Optional.ofNullable(a).map(A::getB).map(B::getC).map(C::getD) .ifPresent(this::doSmtngWithD);`

Comment: @Holger You're probably right. Maybe you should write an answer.

Comment: @Holger , your answer still means B,C,D will be Optionals, right?

Comment: @slashms: no, that’s for the unchanged methods, i.e. potentially returning `null`. See [`Optional.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-): “*If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and if the result is non-null, return an Optional describing the result. Otherwise return an empty Optional*”…